# AcitveXObject fails to create object in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, com, activex, activexobject

I have a dll of a 64-bit .NET 4.0 application, which I register as COM and use in my web application with the help of ActiveXObject.

The dll is get registered successfully and the application get instantiated correctly in IE 8(64-bit).
When I am trying to create object of application in IE 11 it throws exception "automation server can't create object".

I have tried many settings in IE 11 also tried the guy suggest from MCRSFT community like "EnableIEHosting".
I have made the IE 11 settings as mirror of my working IE8(64-bit) but not worked.

Anybody let me know, Am I missing something in IE 11 that IE 8(64-bit) has?

Note- To instantiate the COM dll I'm using Javascript as below

```
var viewer=new ActiveXObject("My.Viewer");
```

where- my application is registered under "My.Viewer" name.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @RGraham the code contains right spelling, this is typo error by me while typing over here, my apologies.